# How to add conditional statements in supervisord configuration file

Tags: environment-variables, conditional-statements, supervisord

I'm starting a python script with supervisord on a linux debian platform. The user selected for executing the script shall depend on the value of an environmental variable. How can i make the field "user=" in a supervisord configuration file conditional?

First, I have added to the supervisor.service an environmental variable `SPECIALUSER=myuser` (file /lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service)

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
ExecStop=/usr/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown
ExecReload=/usr/bin/supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf $OPTIONS reload
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
Environment=SPECIALUSER=myuser
```

Then I try to use the variable inside my supervisord.conf file:

```
[program:myprogram]
command=python myscript.py
user="if [ %(ENV_SPECIALUSER)s = myuser]; then root; else standarduser; fi"
```

But I get the following error when i try to reread the supervisord.conf

```
ERROR: CANT_REREAD: Invalid user name "if [ myuser = myuser ]; then root; else standarduser; fi" in section 'program:myprogram' (file: '/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf')
```

The environmental variable is interpreted correctly but the bash script, not.

I thought about entering the name of the user directly in the variable `Environment=SPECIALUSER=root`, but the environmental varialble is not always available.

If the environment variable is set to `SPECIALUSER=myuser`, I expect supervisor.d to interpret my program as

```
[program:myprogram]
command=python myscript.py
user=root
```

In all other cases as

```
[program:myprogram]
command=python myscript.py
user=standarduser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the user parameter value is never "interpreted" or sent to a shell. This means that it tries to use the entire value as the username.

http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings

All parameters aren't interpreted or sent to a shell. This means that you can't insert conditionals generally in parameters in your supervisord.conf.

If your goal is to just use different users on say different platforms or one for development and another on a deploymentserver I suggest creating a dedicated user for the service.

If your goal is to only sometimes run as superuser I suggest always using `user=root` in your supervisord.conf and wrapping your program in a small shell script that interprets this environment variable and drops privileges accordingly.

This other SO question might help you:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132663/how-do-i-drop-root-privileges-in-shell-scripts

Comment: Hi @asheidan, thank you for your answer. I wanted to run the program as root only in certain configurations. Because I did not found a solution, i managed to run the program as a normal user, instead as a root user.